# Visual Basic: How do I remove parentheses from a string the user enters?

Tags: vb.net

Sample:

The string: `George (Babe) Ruth`

(calculate) - output:

```
George Ruth
```

How would I go about this in VB?

Comment: MyString.Replace("Babe", "")

Comment: look at the `string.replace` function and `String.IndexOf`

Comment: Do you want to remove teh text inside the parantheses too?

Comment: precision is a beautiful thing

Comment: What would you want to do if the user string was "George (Babe Ruth"?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Regex and do this

```
ResultString = Regex.Replace(SubjectString, "\\(.+\\)", "");
```

Comment: the title says he wants to remove parens, but the example shows he wants to replace the text in them too: `George (Babe) Ruth` ==> `George Ruth` which means eating a space too

Comment: Yes, this is true. I need to remove the content within the parentheses as well.

Comment: @bert Updated answer. This will remove anything that falls between two matching parantheses

Answer (score 0):

It should work as your tag was VB.net.if not the above Regex also works

```
 Dim s2,s,d,g as string 
 s2 = "George (Babe) Ruth "
 s = InStr(1, s2, " (")
 d = InStr(1, s2, ") ")
 g = s2.Remove(s, d + 1 - s)
```

Answer (score 0):

To piggyback on user2526236's answer....

With VB.net use this function - pass in the string with the parens...

```
Private Function RemoveChunk(psString As String) As String
        Dim iStart As Integer
        Dim iStop As Integer
        Dim sModifiedString As String

        iStart = InStr(psString, "(")
        iStop = InStr(psString, ")")

        If iStart > 0 And iStop > 0 Then
            sModifiedString = psString.Remove(iStart - 1, iStop + 1 - iStart)
        Else
            'nothing to modify
            sModifiedString = psString
        End If
        Return sModifiedString
    End Function
```